# Castle Windsor - Register components only once

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

I was wondering if there is some best practice to achive the functionality I need.

I have a web application that during startup, with reflection, scans certain assemblies (plugins) and registers their dependencies against common kernel.

The external libraries may need same dependencies.

For example library A gets scanned and its dependecy D1 is registered. Then library B is scanned and tries to register same dependency - D1 - against kernel again. 
Castle obviously will complain if I try to register same component twice.

My question is: How you usually handle the scenario when you simply want to skip the component that is already registered. Is there some extension method on IWindsorContainer that performs this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can library B contain the same plugin as library A does?

Comment: Its PluginA can contain same dependency (IDependency) as PluginB. They  both run on the same web application and try to register IDependency twice. I'm looking some smart way (maybe extension method on IWindsorContainer.Register) that performs this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use inside your register statement:

```
Component.For<Test>.OnlyNewServices()
```

or when registering multiple components at once:

```
Types.FromAssemblyContaining<Test>().InSameNamespaceAs<Test>().Configure(c => c.OnlyNewServices());
```

Or a variation that suits you. See this link for conditional registration: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Conditional-component-registration.ashx

Comment: Thank you Marwijn! 
Exacly what I was looking for.

Thanks all for contibuting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all your dependencies (services) will be only in those plugin assemblies, you can just go ahead and register every service (I assume you know which types should exactly be registered, i.e. you have them somehow marked) from every plugin assembly. You don't have to resolve any dependencies manually as this will be handled by the container itself, so you don't have to worry about ordering or double registration issues.

Comment: I do not know with dependencies will be registered prior to application bootstrap. 

It depends with plugins (and their relative dependencies) are referenced.

Simply PluginA may need IDependencyA and PluginB may need it as well. Plugins are like black-boxes - they do not know each other. So when PluginA registers its stuff and plugin B as well, Kernel will throw because IDependencyA is already there.

Every plugin has its own IWindsorInstaller.

I need some smart way to just bypass already registered components, that's it.

Comment: Well basically if they have their own IWindsorInstaller, you do not have any control over them. Maybe child containers would solve your problem?